# the version 5.7 of mysql make lock table by default?

Tags: mysql

I'm studying the lock tables but I have some doubts and I can't find the answers about my questions.

I have a database in mysql (*version 5.7*) and a website (*PHP 7.0*) where you can buy some tickets for some concerts.
So, I have a table with the number of tickets for each concerts. 
When a user click on the booking button, I call a procedure in mysql that check if there are tickets and if the answer is positive, decrement the number and make the order.
All the tables have the InnoDB Engine.

**The table**
*name*: concert_ticket
*column*: id (primary key, autoincrement) ,  concert_id, ticket_number

**The code**

```
$querySituation = $db->query("CALL decrementConcert('".$idConcert."',@response)");
$requestSituation = $db->Query("SELECT @response as result;");
$resultProcedure = $requestSituation->fetch_assoc();
if($resultProcedure['result'] != 0){ 
    //insert order
}
```

Now, my questions are:
1. Is it necessaries active lock table in this case?
2. in mysql 5.7, is it expected a lock table by default? or I must to do always this manually in my code?
3. to use the lock table, I have to lock table with a query before the procedure and unlock table after insert?

Comment: *"When a user click on the booking button, I call a procedure in mysql that check if there are tickets and if the answer is positive, decrement the number and make the order."*  You should be looking into InnoDB engine and transactions..

Answer (score 0):

1. First, your table should be using the InnoDB engine, which supports transactions.
2. Second, you should run the following under a trasaction with a `START TRANSACTION;`
3. Your procedure should read the current available ticket count with a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;`. This will lock the row.
4. If the tickets are available, you can then update the available ticket count and `COMMIT` the transaction.
5. If the tickets are not available, you can either `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT` (you have made no changes).

Comment: Thank you so much @Ronald. The table use InnoDB engine, I immediately update the question by also entering this value.